# Data in and changes to app.scss in Ember CLI application not reflected in browser

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-cli, broccolijs

I've recently started my first Ember CLI project, and have loaded broccoli-sass to handle the stylesheets as instructed by various sources. Editing the app.scss with various test css (e.g. body {background-color:red}) that broccoli-sass provides does not result in any changes in the browser. Furthermore, checking project-name.css in the developer tools reveals an empty file--does this mean that app.scss is not being compiled? Am I supposed to manually compile this myself, or is something not happening?

Comment: When I uncovered this problem, I only had an app.scss file. I added back in an app.css file, and changes to the css made on that file are reflected in the browser. Now, what do I do to get all the code in app.scss to compile to app.css? I've already followed all the instructions in https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the latest ember-cli (0.2.3) just run this:

```
ember install ember-cli-sass
```

Put your stylesheet in app/styles/app.scss

And it should just work.

Comment: And what if it doesn't "just work"?.  There's a clear app.scss, but any changes to it don't result in changes on the screen. I think it should be noted that page-one-front.css (page-one-front is the name of my project) is completely empty...nothing in app.scss is getting compiled to that.

Comment: You tried switching from broccoli-sass to ember-cli-sass?   I initially tried broccoli-sass and it did not work out of the box.   After removing that and installing ember-cli-sass it just worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I variety of errors in stylesheets included in app.scss caused app.scss to fail to load. Once these errors were corrected, the file compiled.